# Unable to include Magick++.h for image processing: "no such file or directory"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, imagemagick

I'm setting up a c++ visual studio project to use ImageMagick's api, Magick++, for image processing. However, when I try to `include <Magick++.h>` in the only cpp file in the whole solution/project, I encounter this error:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Magick++.h': No such file or directory
```

I tried right-clicking `Magick++.h` in my code and pressing `open document <Magick++.h>`. This lead to an error message, which says the file is not found in current source file's directory or in build system paths. However, in the error message, the Build System Path clearly says the path to the `include` directory.

I have:

1. added the ***include*** directory of ***ImageMagick-7.0.9-Q16*** in the project's properties->C/C++
   ->Additional Include Directories.
2. added the ***lib*** directory of ***ImageMagick-7.0.9-Q16*** in the project's properties->Linker->Additional Library Directories
3. added *CORE_RL_Magick++_.lib*, *CORE_RL_MagickCore_.lib*, and *CORE_RL_MagickWand_.lib* in the project's properties->Linker->Additional Dependencies
4. Made sure everything is x64
5. Set the configuration to release
6. I somehow made *Magick+++_demo* project, the one that comes with magick++, work after tinkering with the settings. However, I cannot make other projects/solutions work. I have checked the settings of the demo project and tried to replicate it in my project where appropriate, but I cannot make my own project work.

this is the only code:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <Magick++.h>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

I have been googling and trying to make this work for the last 6 hours. Any help is hugely appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried it with `#include <Magick++.h>`?

Comment: Check the include path. Did you add it for all configurations? When you browse to the folder you added to the include directories does `Magick++.h` exist? Is there a space in the path? If so did you use quotation marks?

Comment: @csabinho yes its on line 2 of my main cpp file. Its in the code I posted

Comment: Sorry, I'm an [...]. I meant `#include "Magick++.h"`!

Comment: @drescherjm Yes to all questions.

Comment: @csabinho I just tried it. Same error and result sadly

Comment: Copy the exact path with the quotes to the file explorer and see if that takes you to the correct folder. If it does perhaps you have some other bad path in your include directories above the path you added.

Comment: I think you just solved my problem. Now I feel stupid. I asked a question on stack overflow just for someone to help me correct my file path...

Comment: Thanks so much guys. Really appreciate it.